# Running python shell in terminal with file?

Tags: python, terminal

As a young, pre-university programming enthusiast, I have recently become addicted to using Vim.

I'm thinking of attempting to move all my programming over to the terminal (in order to use Vim more) but one thing is stopping me: traditional IDEs for Python have an interactive shell. This shell is "restarted" upon me executing a file and allows me to interact/compute with functions in this file after a scripted computation is completed.

**How is this done in the terminal?** I understand that you can call up a general Python terminal but not one where it executes some code and then, afterwards (potentially thanks to a keyboard interrupt), allows you to work with the code interactively.

Comment: I think you can execute commands inside of Vim but if you're looking for this type of functionality you'll really only get it in an IDE. You can run your code, edit it, and then run it again, which is what I do.

Comment: Hi Isky, I am a programmer with more than 7 years of experience. In my case I also use VIM and I have added some tweaks from [vimawesome.com](https://vimawesome.com/) In my experience I don't use an IDE, my python setup is based in [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) which can be configured in your terminal. I have to say that I work on Linux, and is easier for me to have a pure terminal setup that it is on Windows.

Comment: I have vim in one terminal and a separate terminal in the same directory, potentially using a virtualenv. If I want to get to the shell after running a script I simply run `python -i myscript.py arg1 arg2` . Its the "-i" that puts into the shell.

Answer (score 0):

A really great command line tool for python is [IPython](https://ipython.org/)

IPython is a wrapper around the python interpreter which adds additional functionality, and allows you to create custom "magic" plugins. Once nice feature is you can bring up an editor like vim with the edit command and edit a file, or lines in your IPython history.